# Unstable server

Tags: windows-xp

I would like to know what could be the reasons for XP server to keep inaccessible. We have checked many devices and even thought of virus detecting but it seemed no results.

The pop out window says the reason I am not able to access the server is because there are too many connections/users on the servers. In fact we only have 5 users and the maximum users for the server are 10.

Comment: Have you checked in the task manager if all sessions are properly logged off? not just disconnected.

Comment: 1 User != 1 Connection

Answer (score 6):

First, this is a licensing issue. Second, there are most likely lingering connections, a restart might fix the problem.

But a better solution would be: Don't use Windows *XP* for a server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect to the server via Remote Desktop? If so, note that by design only one remote PC and user can connect at a time to a XP RDP host computer. The RDP host display is locked out when a remote user connects.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280828